# font-weight 500 and 600 not working on input element

Tags: css, webfonts

Values `500` and `600` of `font-weight` don't work on `input` element. `500` scales down rendering `400` version of the font and `600` up to `700`. It behaves this way both in Firefox and Chrome. Why does it happen? Is there a way to make inputs render `500` as well?

Here's a pen illustrating the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPYPVg

Comment: You're not using your custom fonts. Add class `.roboto` to your inputs.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about font-fmaily: inherit on the `input`. Thanks!

Comment: Try to set the right font class on the inputs like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwmbwO

Comment: Is there an echo in here?

Comment: Sorry, Chad... Chad.. chad.. ad.....  I overlooked your comment.. comment ..omment ..mmnt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the font family for your inputs. It wont work otherwise as the input doesnt recognize the font Open Sans or roboto

```
font-family: "Open Sans";

OR

font-family:"Roboto"
```

Comment: Why doesn't input inherit from the body?